# how to extract and save HTML table as Json with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to extract all the content of a table with Selenium IDE, for small tables it works very well, however for large tables it takes a lot of time. With Selenium IDE I can extract the HTML structure of the table and store into a variable as String. I was wondering if is posible to get the content of the table with JavaScript more faster and save it into a Json.

The HTML table will be stored into a variable: `var htmlTable = '<table id="customers"> ... </table>'`

```
<table id="customers">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

for example save the data like this:

```
[{
        "Company": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "Contact": "Maria Anders",
        "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "Contact": "Francisco Chang",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Ernst Handel",
        "Contact": "Roland Mendel",
        "Country": "Austria"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Island Trading",
        "Contact": "Helen Bennett",
        "Country": "UK"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Laughing Bacchus Winecellars",
        "Contact ": "Yoshi Tannamuri",
        "Country ": "Canada"
    },
    {
        "Company": "Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti",
        "Contact": "Giovanni Rovelli",
        "Country": "Italy"
    }
]
```

Comment: Note that you haven't actually asked a question in your post. Your title is a summary of the problem you have, it is not the question itself. So: what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

this  way...

```js
const
  cTCols   = document.querySelector('table#customers thead')
, cTdata   = document.querySelector('table#customers tbody')
, colsName = [...cTCols.rows[0].cells].map(c=>c.textContent.trim())
, result   = [...cTdata.rows].reduce((arr,{cells})=>
    {
    let data = [...cells].reduce((o,{textContent: val},i)=>
        (o[colsName[i]]=val.trim(), o), {})
    arr.push(data)
    return arr
    }, [])

console.log(result)
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding : .2em .8em;
  border  : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color : aquamarine;
  }
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <thead>
    <tr><th> Company </th><th> Contact </th><th> Country </th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td> Alfreds Futterkiste          </td><td> Maria Anders     </td><td> Germany </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Centro comercial Moctezuma   </td><td> Francisco Chang  </td><td> Mexico  </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Ernst Handel                 </td><td> Roland Mendel    </td><td> Austria </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Island Trading               </td><td> Helen Bennett    </td><td> UK      </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Laughing Bacchus Winecellars </td><td> Yoshi Tannamuri  </td><td> Canada  </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti </td><td> Giovanni Rovelli </td><td> Italy   </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```